# How to I write image and text data sequentially to a NSDocumentDirectory File?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to write code to create a simplistic photo journal.  You select an image, write it to a file, and then add a text description.  Below is my code.  I can write the image or the text, but not both sequentially.  One or the other writes over the other.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Since iPhone simulator doesn't have photos, load and display a placeholder image
    NSString *fPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_1588" ofType:@"jpg"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fPath];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

//    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1588.jpg"];

    // Create the file to write the image
    NSArray *DocumentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [DocumentsDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.doc"];

    //Creating a file at this path
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL ok = [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    if (!ok) {NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", filePath);}
    else {

    //Writing image to the created file
    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

    // move to the end of the file to add data
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
//    [myHandle writeData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];
    [myHandle closeFile];
    }
}
    // User provides a caption for the image
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

    NSString *caption = enterCaption.text;

    NSArray *DocumentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [DocumentsDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.doc"];

    ///Creating a file at this path
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL ok = [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    if (!ok) {NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", filePath);}
    else {

        //Writing image to the created file
        NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

        // move to the end of the file to add data
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [myHandle writeData:  [caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [myHandle closeFile];
    }
}

    //Disness Keyboard
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use createFileAtPath. Only use that if the file does not exist, otherwise just open the file.

EDIT: log the size of everything for no to see if things appear normal.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I was too tired to see this.  When I test the existing of the file with if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath], YES) it works fine, but if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath], NO) does not work.  Any ideas why or suggestions.  Two other things: (1) I can't figure out how to save the image to a file that can be read with NSFileManager, suggestion? and (2) do you know how to put a return into a file with NSFileManager so I can separate these entries?

Comment: Additional comment.  Right now when I write the image to the file, it generates +100 pages of nonsense versus an image.  My goal is to create a file that has the image followed by a caption, and allow the user to print this file out like a journal.

Comment: Create a folder for each entry, put the text in one file and the image in another inside the folder.